# Force.com License Cancellation - How Long Is Metadata Retained?

Tags: force.com, licenses

Supposed that our org has temporarily cancelled our Force.com licenses and after two years we want to renew these again, will the app built on it still be there?

Comment: You should be using version control anyway.

Comment: uh...what's with the voting to close this as opinion-based? My answer is clearly based on an official source, and Adrian's comment could be turned into a serviceable answer as well. I'm voting to re-open.

Comment: I agree that it's not opinion based, but I'll let the community decide here. :)

Comment: This doesn't sound opinion based to me neither, this is something you would expect salesforce to be able to answer exactly. And thus possible community members who have experience with this should be expected to be able to answer too, without guessing or relying on opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Two years sounds a little more than "temporary" to me, and "this is just a question" tends to be more reality than hypothetical in my experience.

It took a little digging, but it appears that this is laid out in the [Master Subscription Agreement](https://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_MSA.pdf) that needs to be signed as part of signing up to use Salesforce.

At time of writing, the MSA contained the following

> **12.5. Your Data Portability and Deletion.**
>   Upon
>    request
>     by You
>    made
>     within
>    30 days
>    after
>    the
>     effective
>     date
>     of 
>   termination
>     or  expiration
>     of  this
>     Agreement,
>     We
>     will 
>   make
>     Your
>     Data 
>   available
>     to  You
>     for     export
>     or  download
>     as 
>   provided in the Documentation. After such 30
>   -day period, We will have no obligation to maintain or provide any
>    Your
>   Data, and as provided in the Documentation will thereafter delete or destroy all copies of Your Data in Our systems
>    or 
>   otherwise in Our possession or control, unless legally
>    prohibited.

The term 'your data' is defined as

> “
>   Your  Data
>   ” means electronic data and information submitted by or for Customer to the Services, excluding
>     Content 
>   and Non
>   -SFDC
>    Applications.

Now, I am not a lawyer, but "your data" could simply mean the records (in sObjects, both standard and custom) stored within Salesforce, or it could include code and other configuration as well. This would be something to ask to Salesforce directly (or your lawyer, if you/your company has one).

The bottom line is that Salesforce will retain "data" for 30 days, and allow you to download it. After 30 days, your data is likely deleted (or scheduled for deletion at the very least), and Salesforce likely won't allow you access to it.

Comment: Good sleuthing. I am not a lawyer either, but it seems pretty clear to me that the MSA definition of 'Your Data' includes metadata. It's also the case that SFDC is not committing to a timeframe for deletion of "Your Data," just that they have no obligation past 30 days, and at some point "thereafter" will delete. But unlikely that they keep it for 2+ years.

Answer (score 0):

I can't directly address the question you asked, but I would recommend that you back up any metadata you wish to save for the long term in a `Version Control` system. In addition to allowing you to restore applications that have been dormant for years, it provides you a rollback plan in case a deployment goes awry or has unintended consequences. It's a pretty basic cornerstone of professional development and is widely viewed as an industry best practice. It also helps you institute formalized code review, and has many other benefits as well. Probably the most common options in the field are Git and Subversion.